# I am trying to create a formula to calculate unit dimensions from case dimensions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, calculator

This is kind of a specific question but I am attempting to calculate the dimensions of a unit within a case given the case dimensions. However, there are several configurations and counts for the units. The most common configurations and counts are (12 count 4X3X1), (24 count 6X4X1) and (24 count 4X3X2)(Units in LXWXH). I have calculated the cut-off case height to be 5.5 inches where anything above that must be the 2 high configuration of 4X3X2 assuming it is 24 count. Given only this information, is it possible to create a general formula or calculator?

Thanks.

```html
+------+--------+--------+--------+--+---------+-------+
| Case | Height | Length | Width  |  | Volume  | Count |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--+---------+-------+
|      |      4 |      7 |   5.25 |  |     147 |    12 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |   7.75 |  |     354 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |   7.75 |  |     354 |    12 |
|      |    3.5 |    7.5 |    5.5 |  |     144 |    12 |
|      |   7.75 |     10 |      9 |  |     698 |    60 |
|      |      7 |   6.75 |   5.75 |  |     272 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.25 |   7.25 |  |     316 |    24 |
|      |      7 |  14.25 |    8.5 |  |     848 |    24 |
|      |      7 |  14.25 |      9 |  |     898 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.25 |   7.25 |  |     316 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |   10.5 |   7.25 |  |     324 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |   7.25 |  |     331 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |   7.25 |  |     331 |    24 |
|      |    6.5 |     19 |   12.5 |  |    1544 |    48 |
|      |   5.51 |  10.51 |   7.95 |  |     460 |    12 |
|      |   6.85 |   6.69 |      5 |  |     229 |    24 |
|      |   7.28 |   7.48 |   5.59 |  |     304 |    24 |
|      |   8.78 |   9.06 |   6.89 |  |     548 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |    7.5 |  |     343 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |    7.5 |  |     343 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |  10.75 |   7.75 |  |     354 |    24 |
|      |   4.25 |   11.5 |      8 |  |     391 |    24 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--+---------+-------+
```

Comment: This really needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: It mostl likely is possible, but it's impossible to figure out what exactly is the problem if you don't include a sample.

Comment: My apologies, I added a sample of the data above.

Comment: We still need expected results for 2 or 3 of the cases above.  Is the result supposed to be the Count column?    Are there only three units?   4x3x1  and 6x4x1  and  4x3x2  ?   Or is the result to compute a possible unit size?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify. The 4x3x1 and 6x4x1 and 4x3x2 are the three possible configurations of the units within the case. Meaning, 4x3x1 would have 4 columns of units and 3 rows of units placed in the case with only one layer, adding up to 12 units. 4x3x2 would be the same thing but two layer high, adding up to 24 units. Using this information and the dimensions of the case, I am trying to calculate an approximate item dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Had a lot of fun with this. Not sure if this is what you want 100% but will likely help. The code allows you to select a config, and it displays an output of what the stacks look like. All data stuff is done with formulas, which are in the photo. GL

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I3:I5")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Dim rngClear As Range
            Set rngClear = ActiveSheet.Range("C14:AA100")

        rngClear.ClearFormats

        Dim str As String
            str = Target.Value

        str = Replace(str, Left(str, 5), "")

        Dim arr() As String
            arr = Split(str, "x")

        Dim count As Long
            count = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Target.Row)

        count = count / arr(2)

        Dim perCase As Long
            perCase = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Target.Row)

        Dim startCol As Long
            startCol = 3

        Dim startRow As Long
            startRow = 16

        Dim rngObj As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim runLoop As Boolean
            runLoop = True

        Do While runLoop = True
            Dim strtRng As Range
                Set strtRng = ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow, startCol)
            Dim endRng As Range
                Set endRng = ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow + CInt(arr(1) - 1), startCol + CInt(arr(0)) - 1)

            Set rngObj = ActiveSheet.Range(strtRng.Address, endRng.Address)

            For Each cell In rngObj
                If count = 0 Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If arr(2) = 1 Then
                    cell.Interior.color = vbRed
                Else
                    cell.Interior.color = vbBlue
                End If
                count = count - 1
            Next cell
         startCol = startCol + CInt(arr(0) + 1)
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, what i was looking for was the smaller item dimensions which go inside a case (12, 24 and 24). If i interpenetrated it correctly, you multiplied the given dimensions of the case and multiplied it by the configuration of the items. I wanted to find a measurement of each individual unit that sits inside a case using a general formula. For example, in the case of a 6x4x1 case there a 24 units, given the width is 6 units long i would theoretically simply divide the given case length by 6. I wanted to create a formula that would apply this logic and consider the variables.

Comment: area of case / number of units would get you area per item. then you could adjust Width Length and Height of the items as you please, so long as the shape you make is rectangular. is this closer ?